# Compare two distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that $N\sim(0,1)$ and I have two functions $f$ and $g$.

Are there any theorems or techniques for comparing how close are distributions of $f(N)$ and $g(N)$?

For example, it is known that sum of lognormal random variables $ae^{bN}+ce^{dN}$ can be approximated by one lognormal variable $ue^{vN}$. Is it possible to find how good approximation is?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to google ""statistical distance" or "Lévy–Prokhorov metric".

Comment: @LidingYao , any simple example would be great.

Comment: Check the definitions from wikipedia.